# Using update-able FlowDocument XAML files as my WPF help system

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, flowdocument

I'm putting together a simple help system for my WPF app using XAML FlowDcouments (just .xaml files, no code-behind). I've simply added them to my project with Build Action = Resource, and I can load and display them as required.

Now, I'm trying to make it a bit more flexible, in that after the installation of the app, I want the user to be able to download additional (or newer versions of the existing) FlowDocument XAML help files. Given this, I'm now wondering where the best place to store these files is. A few questions/ideas:

- Can I leave them as resource files, and overwrite or add new files as required? I can't find a example of how to add/edit resources at runtime on SO/Google. Is it even possible?
- If not, is there a recommended location to store these files? They should be available to all users, so they can't go into the User's directory - they would have to go in the program directory. Does the program directory have write-access (I remember having issues with that before)?
- Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource files are embedded into the executable and therefore you cannot change them.

As for a common place to put your downloaded help files, you cannot store them in "Program Files" since you would need admin privileges to write there.

I suggest you put them into **SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData** (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.80).aspx), which is defined as **"The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users."**